# Setting minimum date in to todays date in MVC 4

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

In my view I am allowing the user to enter a start date for a project but I need to validate the HTML to ensure they do not enter a date before today's date, I am aware of min="2015-09-21", but this will not help me in the future, can some please recommend the best way to solve this problem.

```html
<label for="text2">&nbsp;&nbsp;3: Hand-in Date:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
<input type="date" id="date1" name="date1"  >
```

Comment: use a viewmodel and do a test against `DateTime.Now.Date`?

Comment: One option would be to have a property for `MinDate` and then use `min="Model.MinDate"` (and you control has `name="date1"` so it should be `<label for"date1" ...`) but since you have tagged this asp.net-mvc and razor, perhaps you should consider using them :)

Comment: @user1666620 can you explain how that works please, I'm new to MVC

Comment: Hi @StephenMuecke is just a matter of creating something like public DateTime minDate = DateTime.Now in my model then call  it?

Comment: Exactly, But if you want client and server side validation, you should consider a [foolproof](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) `[GreaterThanOrEqualTo]` or similar validation attribute on you property

Comment: Thanks Stephen I will give this a try